# I can't get 'browserify' to recognize file path, Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, gulp, browserify

In essence I am getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`

In the console it points to:

```
var fooBarGold = require('../bower_components/scrollup/dist/lib/jquery-1.11.1.min.js');
```

So in the file `(jquery.scrollUp.js)` I am trying to leverage browserify, I have the above;

and that file I am trying to import(in this case `jquery-1.11.1.min.js`) is wrapped like so:

```
module.exports = function(){
 //jquery
};
```

This is my gulp task:

```
gulp.task('browserify', ['scripts'], function() {
    return browserify('./builds/development/js/app.js')
        .bundle()
        .pipe(source('app.js'))
        .pipe(gulpif(env === 'production', gulp.dest(outputDir + 'js')));

});
```

and this is my script task, (Please note: As you can see by the length of my script task, I'd love to move to browserify so I can get rid of all the streamque)

```
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
return streamqueue({
            objectMode: true
        },
        gulp.src('builds/development/bower_components/jquery/jquery.js'),
        gulp.src('builds/development/bower_components/fastclick/lib/fastclick.js'),
        gulp.src('builds/development/bower_components/mixitup/src/jquery.mixitup.js'),
        gulp.src('builds/development/bower_components/flexslider/jquery.flexslider.js'),
        gulp.src('builds/development/bower_components/angular/angular.js'),
        gulp.src('builds/development/bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js'),
        gulp.src('builds/development/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js'),
        gulp.src('builds/development/bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js'),
        gulp.src('builds/development/bower_components/angular-flexslider/angular-flexslider.js'),
        gulp.src('builds/development/bower_components/angular-foundation/mm-foundation-tpls.js'),
        gulp.src('builds/development/bower_components/foundation/js/vendor/modernizr.js'),
        gulp.src('components/js/rustyApp.js'),
        gulp.src('components/js/share.js'),
        gulp.src('builds/development/bower_components/uikit/js/uikit.js'),
        // gulp.src('builds/development/bower_components/scrollup/dist/lib/jquery-1.11.1.min.js'),
        gulp.src('builds/development/bower_components/scrollup/dist/jquery.scrollUp.js'),
        gulp.src('builds/development/bower_components/foundation/js/foundation.js'),
        gulp.src('components/js/index_scripts.js'))
    .pipe(jshint())
    .pipe(concat('app.js'))
    // browserify('development/js/app.js')
    // .pipe(source('app.js'))
    // .pipe(gulpif(env === 'production', ngAnnotate()))
    .pipe(gulpif(env === 'production', uglify({
        mangle: false
    }).on('error', function(e) {
        console.log('\x07', e.message);
        return this.end();
    })))

.pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(notify({
        message: "Script tasks have been completed!"
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(outputDir + 'js'));
```

Comment: What does `'./builds/development/js/app.js'` look like?  This question seems like its well crafted, but I'm having trouble understanding exactly where your issue is.

Comment: Currently, I'm not sure you understand exactly how browserify actually works either.  Which may be a part of the issue. Try reading this - https://github.com/substack/browserify-handbook

Comment: Hey thanks for responding Kelly and your comment about being my question being a well crafted inquiry. Not sure why I got down-voted. Anyway, I'll look at the docs. From what I gathered from other resources, doesn't browserify bring in code that another code base needs? My goal was to make my js task cleaner...Thanks again.

Comment: Also, not sure what you meant about what does app.js look like? Well there's no j.query in there, if that's what you meant...

Comment: You require the files you need, or shim them if all are required.

Comment: You wont modify the libraries. Thats not the way you should be doing it.

Comment: I am not trying to modify them, just trying to include them. Like in my example, I want browserfify to include the jQuery for the scrollUp.js file...

Comment: Is scrollup a library? If so, your approach is incorrect.

Comment: ScrollUp is a plugin...

Comment: You should read the docs.